# Exposing a web application to the global network using Kubernetes

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, kubernetes, amazon-ec2, containers

i'm new to K8S, trying some exercises for the first time.
i'm trying to expose a simple web app (nginx) to the outer network. i'm working on an EC2 instance, with elastic ip (for a static ip address).
my deployment.yml file looks like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx-deployment
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx-deployment
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: "nginx:latest"
        name: nginx
        ports:
          - containerPort: 80
```

after running the commands:

```
kubectl apply -f deployment.yml
kubectl expose deployment nginx-deployment --name my-service --port 8080 --target-port=80 --type=NodePort
```

i would expect that i could address this simple app by the elastic ip:port (in my situation - 8080). can't connect.
i've tried to see details about my app via the command:

```
kubectl get services my-service
```

and got this:

```
NAME         TYPE       CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
my-service   NodePort   10.99.98.56   <none>        8080:32725/TCP   26m
```

i've also tried to open ALL OF THE PORTS in my instance - to check if there's any connection. what i did manage to do is to retrieve the internal ip address with:

```
kubectl get nodes -o wide
```

and then by adding the port number (the 32725) with the curl command - i've managed to get the nginx base html page.
my question is this: why couldn't i get the nginx base page via the elastic ip?
and how can i access my simple app?

Comment: You must kubectl port-forward,read more https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/.

Comment: are you running minikube cluster in the ec2?

Comment: @Adiii i'm running the minikube on ec2 instance

Comment: so its mean "VM inside another VM" that's why you can not reach the service using static IP. you need to run `minikube service my-service` then you will be able to reach the service from static IP. or `minikube service my-service &> /dev/null &` if you run in the background.

Comment: @Adiii just to be sure i understood you correctly: when i run minikube on ec2 - i'm actually running a vm over a vm? that's why my elastic ip don't really help me - because my ec2 (with the elastic ip) is actually spinning up another vm with another ip address - which is shown when running the "minikube service my-service" command?

Comment: `minikube service my-service` it create tunnel to host, so you can reach the service from host, if you want to have minikube bare metal then consider this https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/none/

Comment: i'm sorry, but even after doing so - still can't reach my app, nor my dashboard. what am i missing here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247245/discussion-between-adiii-and-gilad-tayeb).